# RS485 how to tell if HXPS-2108F Prolific is working

Tags: driver, inverter, rs485

newbie at electronics (not PC's or software) - my first project is to connect the PC up to a Solar Power Inverter to datalog.  Aurora inverter.. great wiki here http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/solar_software

[image]

From a PC point of view, I've got a logger http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor  seeing what is coming in on the port COM15.  Nothing.

The USB-RS485 converter is an HXSP-2108F (which people have trouble with).  Laptop is Win7-64bit.

Question:  Before I throw this converter away, any suggestions for testing it?

I guess I need a multimeter and see if any voltage is coming down the rs485 wires?

Comment: This looks like a software issue (something like driver configuration), and as such is off-topic.

Comment: Ahh.. apols..if I get this sorted out I'll post a link.

Comment: @stevenvh Although very tangential, getting com ports working is something I have had to fight with MANY times in my short career and seems useful to embedded, would you disagree?

Comment: @Kortuk - indeed tangential. But if the micro clearly sends data, but Hyperterminal receives garbage because the bit-rate is wrong, or receives nothing because the wrong port is set in the FTDI virtual COM driver, then you're away from the microcontroller. Often by more than 1 meter, depending on cable length :-).

Comment: @stevenvh I just consider it a related tool, I myself will not mod vote to close it, I will let the high rep community vote their will.

Comment: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1966464 For all who search a solution with the same Problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, and great help by [this guy](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1966464) where he described a loopback test (which didn't work..) I gave up on this device.

Bought [another one](http://www.thepowerstore.com/product.asp?ID=2804) which is now working perfectly.